# Htaccess IP address Deny Limit

Tags: apache, .htaccess, internal-server-error

I built hta access file with deny all list of proxy ips which I gathered from all the free proxy websites and some of the premium  for my apache server on Ubuntu 18.04. It works and ban the list. However, when the number of ips in the list exceed probably 200, it give me this error

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

I opened the log file and this was the result

```
[Tue Feb 25 02:30:01.233297 2020] [core:alert] [pid 3118] [client 127.0.0.1:48874] /var/www/html/.htaccess: deny requires at least two arguments, 'from' followed by hostnames or IP-address wildcards
```

I got no idea about what is wrong as it works with small list of ips but not many (10000 ips)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

I found the soltuion, one of my ip list was empty

```
deny from 47.73.177.8192
deny from
deny from 132.478.372.478
```

Thanks though for your help